# If there is a non-slipping string pulling a cylindrical object, is the rotational acceleration the same as the translational acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

The rotational velocity and translational velocity are the same right? Assuming the cylindrical object does not interact with anything other than the string which applies a force.

Comment: how are you defining rotational acceleration? In the usual definition, rotational acceleration doesn't have the same unit as translational acceleration, so I don't think they can be the same

Comment: How does the string pull the cylinder? If you keep on pulling the string, eventually there'll be no rotational velocity if the force is perpendicular to the surface of the cylinder...

Comment: Well, the string is wrapped around a cylinder, and assume it's never ending.

Comment: In your title you ask about accelerations; in the body you ask about velocities. Which is it (or both)?

Comment: I'm asking for both.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so, am assuming you have put the axis of rotation through the height of the cylinder, such that at a cross section it is a rolling circle.

In this case the angular acceleration $$\alpha$$ is about such an axis that is set up relative to the body of the cylinder i.e center of mass, where as the translational acceleration's (a) axis is set up relative the cylinders spatial frame.

You would add the Lagrangian for both the body frame and spatial frame and solve from there.